# Why the addone button is lost when I enable panel code?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Once the `require("sdk/panel").Panel` code is enabled, I cannot find the addone button, even cannot find it in customize page, what's wrong?

[image]

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var data = require("sdk/panel").data;

// var okentry=require("sdk/panel").Panel({
//   contentURL: data.url("okentry.html"),
//   contentScriptFile: data.url("okentry.js")
// });

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "test-panel",
  label: "ok",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open("https://www.baidu.com/");
  // okentry.show();
  alert('hi');
  console.info(tabs.length);
}
```

Comment: You appear to be following the example from [Adding a Button to the Toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Adding_a_Button_to_the_Toolbar). Assuming you are using the icons provided in that example, your screenshot appears to clearly show the new button (the Firefox logo). Maybe I am not understanding what you mean when you say "addone".  The text "addone" does not exist in the code you have provided, so it is unclear as to what you are actually attempting to refer.  The only button created by your code is the one with ID="test-panel".

Comment: yes, i am following that example, i mean when i use code like require("sdk/panel").Panel, i cannot see the button again, why?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is this line :

```
var data = require("sdk/panel").data;
```

but you should write :

```
data = require("sdk/self").data;
```

as require("sdk/panel") has no "data", the variable became undefined. Later, when you call data.url("okentry.html"), browser throws exception and Panel constructor and all code below is not executed.

Comment: Could you add more explanation to your answer? It will be more helpful.

Comment: It looks like simple typo, but I've added explanation.