# Why I cannot set breakpoint at some of the jetpack code?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

I set two breakpoint as the following screenshot shows, then I click the example plugin, to my surprised, the debugger seems to just ignore these two breakpoints, why? Is that debuggabe for the initialization code of jetpack plugin?

This question is a bit related to [Why the addone button is lost when I enable panel code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710818/why-the-addone-button-is-lost-when-i-enable-panel-code-when-using-jetpack), I set this breakpoint in order to know what is in require ("sdk/panel").data

[image]

debug from addone manager
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Those lines of code are run when the browser starts, way before you add the breakpoints.

Put a breakpoint on line 22, then click your action button. It should work as expected.

Edit:

If you want to add breakpoints to initiation code, you'll need to use Waldimir Palant's [extension auto-installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoinstaller/). This allows you to live-reload the extension and your breakpoints will trigger.

The downside is that if you've made changes to the js files in between installations, the old files will be displayed until you relaunch the debugger.

Comment: will jetpack support breakpoint in initialization code in the future?

Comment: See my edit above. Not sure if there are plans to make this the default behavior.